# Display a LI that is held under a different parent

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I currently have a navigation that is based on the bellow image. (sorry about the terrible sketch) I have a tab along the top called "films" that is also classed as a department.
I would like the tab "films" to open the sub cat films located in the department tab as though the mouse was hovered over that.

Currently the department "films" is a list item under an ordered list of department and has an ID of MM05.
The tab "films" is again another li in an unordered list for the top bar that originally had its own drop down.

Not sure how I can get around this!

[image]

Comment: provide HTML, CSS code.

Comment: It's probably not doable. You'd have to call the hover event on the nearest common ancestor siblings, which is likely too broad of a selector. This is why the gods blessed us with jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is sadly not possible just using CSS as "Cascading" means that you can only go downwards with your selectors.

You would have to use Javascript for this.

This would look something like this

```
<script>
  var linkToOpenDropDown=document.getElementbyId("filmLink");
  var dropDown=document.getElementbyId("dropDownList");
  linkToOpenDropDown.onmouseover=function() {
    dropDown.style.visibility='visible';
  };
  linkToOpenDropDown.onmouseout=function() {
    dropDown.style.visibility='hidden';
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your drawing, I am thinking you will have a static DIV that holds a sub menu. So on click it would "visibility: hidden / visible" change to what  you need. I assume that is the location where you want it to show, so mouse over wouldn't work since you can reach it from the button location with out going mouseout...

Please do provide little more code or info on this, thanks.

If i understood correctly, I would make that a onclick (show, hide) type DIV, and have that div with LI use onMouseOver Show / Hide additional panels